# Blazor Server: Can't deploy with nginx on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, blazor, blazor-server-side

So I've been battling a few issues where my project built fine on Windows but wouldn't build, run or publish on Linux. I finally managed to get it to publish, and now I'm receiving a 502 Default Gateway status.

It seems the transition of dotnet between OS' isn't as smooth as MS portrayed. I keep receiving this in my nginx error logs:
`2020/11/27 13:50:50 [error] 35926#35926: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.101.99.238, server: m.b.d.dev.socktest.jan, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "m.b.d.dev.socktest.jan"`

Can anyone help?

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name m.b.d.dev.socktest.jan;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

    server_name m.b.d.dev.socktest.jan;

    root /g/d/t/www/blazor-app-utility/root;


    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of linux is that?

Comment: @Evk I am using Ubuntu, which is based on Debian.

Comment: What happens if you do curl or wget of http://localhost:5000 from server itself (without nginx)?

Comment: @Evk both HTTP and HTTPS local versions are up (5000, and 5001) of the Blazor application.